# power bi Playground

Tags: gulp, powerbi

I have been struggling to run the powerBI playground using Gulp or Visual Studio on Windows 10.I havent tried on any other windows version yet.

I followed all the steps provided at below URL:

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-core

When use the command - gulp playground , a URL is launched in the browser. But no visualization is available and all the dropdowns are empty.

When I use the command - `gulp build` , I'm receiving many errors like one below:

> ```
> ERROR in ./src/Clients/PowerBIVisualsTests/visuals/verticalSlicerTests.ts
> Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEmitOutput' of null
>   at Object.loader (C:\PowerBI-visuals\node_modules\ts-loader\index.js:422:33)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To run the project in Visual Studio, you need to copy the `PowerBI-visuals-core\lib` folder to `PowerBI-visuals-core\src\Clients\PowerBIVisualsPlayground`.

[Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-core/issues/481). (Not sure if this will help with `gulp build`)